# Find contiguous index until certain field changes

Tags: mysql, sql, algorithm

I have some data in a MySQL server that has an index number from 0 to 15, and two other fields that contain a name and an address.

```
Name    Address Index
-----   ------- --
Test    0x0100  0
Test    0x0100  1
Test    0x0100  2
Test    0x0100  3
Test    0x0100  4
Test2   0x0100  5
Test2   0x0100  6
Test2   0x0100  7
Test    0x0100  8
Test    0x0100  9
Test    0x0100  10
Test3   0x0100  11
Test3   0x0100  12
Test    0x0100  13
Test    0x0100  14
Test    0x0100  15
```

The data is sorted by address and then index.

I would like to summarize this data with the range of indices when each index, like the following:

```
Name    Address Start   End
-----   ------- -----   ----
Test    0x0100  0       4
Test2   0x0100  5       7
Test    0x0100  8       10
Test3   0x0100  11      12
Test    0x0100  13      15
```

Is there a way to do this in MySQL? Alternatively, Is there an efficient algorithm to accomplish this other than brute force? Some post processing is possible after the query returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in MySQL, using variables:

```
select name, address, min(index) as start_index, max(index) as end_index
from (select t.*,
             (@grp := if(@name = name, @grp,
                        if(@name := name, @grp + 1, @grp + 1)
                       )
             ) as grp
      from t cross join
           (select @grp := 0, @name := '') params
      order by index
     ) t
group by name, address, grp;
```

Here is a working version.

Comment: `t` is the table from which the original records are from? I understand we're using a derived table here but I don't seem to be getting the correct output

Comment: @anthozep . . . `t` is the original table.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I'm not sure I get the correct result: The http://rextester.com/BYV90313 "Test" should be split out into three groups as in my original question. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: @anthozep . . . My fingers didn't type `:=` correctly.

Comment: Works perfectly! There's a subtle difference between = and := I gather?

Comment: @anthozep . . . There is a big difference.  In a `SELECT` statement, `:=` assigns a variable and `=` does a binary comparison.