# Find contiguous field until field changes and add sequence number to rows with the same name

Tags: mysql, sql

This builds on this question: [Find contiguous index until certain field changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44637569/find-contiguous-index-until-certain-field-changes)

Essentially there is data that looks like this

```
Name    Address Index
-----   ------- --
Test    0x0100  0
Test    0x0100  1
Test    0x0100  2
Test    0x0100  3
Test    0x0100  4
Test2   0x0100  5
Test2   0x0100  6
Test2   0x0100  7
Test    0x0100  8
Test    0x0100  9
Test    0x0100  10
Test3   0x0100  11
Test3   0x0100  12
Test    0x0100  13
Test    0x0100  14
Test    0x0100  15
```

The data is sorted by address and then index.

And then gets summarized like this based on the answer in my previous question:

```
Name    Address Start   End
-----   ------- -----   ----
Test    0x0100  0       4
Test2   0x0100  5       7
Test    0x0100  8       10
Test3   0x0100  11      12
Test    0x0100  13      15
```

What I would like to do now is append a sequence number to the end of those Names with the same value within the same address space, so something like this:

```
Name    Address Start   End
-----   ------- -----   ----
Test_1    0x0100  0       4
Test2     0x0100  5       7
Test_2    0x0100  8       10
Test3     0x0100  11      12
Test_3    0x0100  13      15
```

Is this possible with MySQL? Stored Procedures are okay.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  You can get the groups using a difference of row numbers.

But if you already have the data, then:

```
select (case when count(*) over (partition by name) = 1 then name
             else concat(name, '_', row_number() over (partition by name order by start))
        end) as name,
       . . .
from (<your query that does the first part here>) t;
```

Window functions are available starting in MySQL 8.0.

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error near "over (partition by name) = 1 then name else concat (name," Is this available in MySQL 5.6?